# Is there a short form for creating hash-map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is there a short form/macro that allows me to do

```
(defn f [a b c]
  {a b c})
```

instead of

```
(defn f [a b c]
  {:a a :b b :c c})
```

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map

Comment: `hash-map` won't work, since he wants the inverse of map destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmacro as-map [& syms]
  (zipmap (map keyword syms) syms))
```

---

Usage:

```
(def a 42)
(def b :foo)

(as-map a b)
;;-> {:a 42 :b :foo}
```

---

Note that to support namespaced keywords, you'd have to drop support for ns aliases if you want to keep it as short:

```
(defmacro as-map [& syms]
  (zipmap (map keyword syms) (map (comp symbol name) syms)))
```

---

Usage:

```
(def a 42)
(def b :foo)

(as-map example/a foo-of/b)
;;-> {:example/a 42 :foo-of/b :foo}
```

---

Advice: Likely not a good idea, saves you a few keyboard hits at the cost of readability and expressivity and flexibility in naming local bindings.

Answer (score 1):

This shows the steps. Remove the println's for actual use:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:gen-class))

(defmacro hasher [& args] 
  (let [keywords      (map keyword args)
        values        args
        keyvals-list  (interleave keywords values)
  ]
    (println "keywords     "  keywords)
    (println "values       "  values)
    (println "keyvals-list "  keyvals-list)
    `(hash-map ~@keyvals-list)
  )
)

(def a 1)
(def b 2)
(println \newline "result: " (hasher a b))

> lein run
keywords      (:a :b)
values        (a b)
keyvals-list  (:a a :b b)

result:  {:b 2, :a 1}
```

Comment: Nice macro for hash-map construction.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old snippet of mine I've had kicking around for a while.

```
(declare ^:private restructure*)

(defn ^:private restructure-1 [m [e k]]
  (cond
    (= :strs e) (reduce #(assoc %1 (name %2) %2) m k)
    (= :keys e) (reduce #(assoc %1 (keyword (namespace %2) (name %2)) %2) m k) 
    :else       (assoc m k (restructure* e))))

(defn ^:private restructure* [form]
  (if-not (map? form)
    form
    (as-> {} v
      (reduce restructure-1 v form)
      `(hash-map ~@(mapcat identity v)))))

(defmacro restructure [form]
  (restructure* form))
```

The idea is that it provides the complement of clojure.core/destructure which goes from a destructuring form to bindings, this captures bindings and constructs a datastructure.

```
(let [x 1 y 2 z 3]
  (restructure {:keys [x y z]}))
;; => {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}
```